# Is there a good tool for translating from Java classes to ActionScript classes?

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3, translation

I'm looking for a tool which can translate from Java classes to ActionScript classes.

Please tell me any tools like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Granite Data Services project contains a code generator: http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/3.+Gas3+Code+Generator

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Christophe! But I can't use Granite DS for Eclipse plugin. It does not appear the window of editable GraniteDS when I right clicked to a project and selected "Add GraniteDS Nature". Why ?